# calling arrays from different methods, why java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Question: what is wrong with my arrays, and how do I fix it?

Details: 
I initialized the array in the main method, and the values were set in one method. I called the array values in a 2nd method, and everything was fine. 
When I tried to call the array in a 3rd method, I got the out of bounds error, even though the size of the array is exactly the same. 
I was trying to call the array in order to copy it, and then sort the 2nd array.

thank you

```
private static  WeatherLocation[] WeatherSpots = new WeatherLocation[6];
private static Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) 
{int Count;

for(Count = 0 ; Count < 6; Count++)
    WeatherSpots[Count] = new WeatherLocation();

WeatherSpots[0].LocationID = "Tciitcgaitc";
WeatherSpots[1].LocationID = "Redwood Haven";
WeatherSpots[2].LocationID = "Barrier Mountains";
WeatherSpots[3].LocationID = "Nina's Folly";
WeatherSpots[4].LocationID = "Scooly's Hill";
WeatherSpots[5].LocationID = "Twin Cones Park";
    SetUp();

    String Command = "";
    while(!Command.equals("Quit"))  {
    Menu();

    System.out.print("Enter Command: ");
    Command = Input.nextLine();

    if(Command.equals("Post"))
        PostTemperatureInfo();
    if(Command.equals("Daily"))
        WeeklyReport();
    else if (Command.equals("HighLow"))
        Sorting();
    }
}

public static void PostTemperatureInfo()
{
    Scanner LocalInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int K;
    int Temp;
    //...then get the values for each location...

    System.out.println( "Enter the Temperature for each weather station below:\n");
    System.out.println( "---------------------------------------------------------------");

    for(K = 0 ; K < 6 ; K++)  {
        System.out.println( "Weather Station: " + WeatherSpots[K].LocationID);  //Display the location of the fishing spot...

        System.out.print( "Enter Temperature:\t");   //Get the count...
        Temp = LocalInput.nextInt();
         System.out.println( "---------------------------------------------------------------");
         WeatherSpots[K].CatchCount = Temp;
        }
    System.out.println("");
     System.out.println("");
     System.out.println("");
}
public static void WeeklyReport()
{
    for(K = 0 ; K < 6 ; K++) 
        {System.out.println( "" + WeatherSpots[K].LocationID +"\t\t" + WeatherSpots[K].CatchCount + "\t\t" + String.format("%.2f", (WeatherSpots[K].CatchCount - 32) * 5 / 9));
}
}

public static void Sorting()
{int K = 0; 

for(K = 0 ; K < 6 ; K++);
    {int [] copycat = new int[K];


    System.arraycopy(WeatherSpots[K].CatchCount, 0, copycat[K], 0, 6);
    System.out.println("" + copycat[K]);
    Arrays.sort(copycat, 0, K);
    System.out.println("Minimum = " + copycat[0]); 
System.out.println("Maximum = " + copycat[K -1]);  

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm certain a bunch of the code in your example isn't relevant to the problem. Could you try and remove all of it that's not involved in causing the error?

Comment: omitting the imports and the class name prevents us from quickly compiling your file. Your private naming conventions make it hard to analyze your code; variables and attributes are conventionally named with lowercase in Java. Sharing loop counters across methods is a bad habit - declare them in the loop header and not prematurely. Your K in `WeeklyReport` is declared outside, obviously as another static variable which prohibits 2 independent usages of your class - obviously you need to read something up about `static`. In `Sorting` you declare another K, which is shadowing your static var...

Comment: What is the 2nd and the 3rd method you're talking about? If we don't need most parts of the program to understand the problem (`menu`), remove the usage of these methods and test, if you still can reproduce the error. Else provide those methods, that we can reproduce your error. What is a WheatherSpot? Maybe you can reproduce the error with an Array of Strings or int, so that we needn't care? Create such an Test with a simple int array. Most likely you will find the error yourself then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are allocating an array `copycat` that is only `K` integers long, and then you are trying to fit 6 elements into it, even when K == 0. I don't understand your code enough to figure out what the right indexes are, but that's the source of your problem.

Actually, I don't believe that your code as posted will compile. This line from `Sorting()`:

```
System.arraycopy(WeatherSpots[K].CatchCount, 0, copycat[K], 0, 6);
```

seems mighty suspicious. The first and third arguments to `System.arraycopy` are supposed to be arrays, but `copycat[K]` is an `int`. Apparently so is `WeatherSpots[K].CatchCount`.

EDIT:

It seems from your comments and code that the `Sorting()` routine is just supposed to print the min and max values of `WeatherSpots[K].CatchCount`. This can be done much more easily than you are doing. Here's one way:

```
public static void Sorting() {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (WeatherLocation loc : WeatherSpots) {
        final int count = loc.CatchCount;
        if (count < min) {
            min = count;
        }
        if (count > max) {
            max = count;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Minimum = " + min); 
    System.out.println("Maximum = " + max);
}
```

Comment: Does that mean i shouldn't say that K = 0 in the for loops? I thought that was required o_O
oops! you are right. i didn't include the external class file
"public class WeatherLocation {
 public String LocationID;
 public int    CatchCount;"

Comment: @user1476390 - You can have K = 0 in the `for` loop, but what are you trying to accomplish inside `Sorting()`? Are you trying to print a sorted list of the `WeatherSpots[K].CatchCount` values? if so, just copy the values over into a single `copycat` array of length `WeatherSpots.length` and then call `Arrays.sort()`. It seems, though, that all you want is the min and max values, which you can get by just scanning the `WeatherSpots` array. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Why not use "array.length" instead of a hard-coded "6"?

Q: I'd really discourage you from using that indentation style, if you can avoid it.

Anyway - this should work (I have *not* tried it myself):

```
public static void Sorting() {
  for(int K = 0 ; K < WeatherSpots.length ; K++) {
     int [] copycat = new int[K];

     System.arraycopy(
       WeatherSpots[K].CatchCount, 0, copycat[K], 0, WeatherSpots.length);
     System.out.println("" + copycat[K]);
     Arrays.sort(copycat, 0, K);
     System.out.println("Minimum = " + copycat[0]); 
     System.out.println("Maximum = " + copycat[K -1]);  
  }
}
```

The main thing was to get rid of the extraneous ";" after the "for()" loop.

Comment: i'm still getting the same errors as before :P But thanks for the fast response

i didn't use array.length because the array's name was "weatherspots[count].catchcount" and i got errors if i added on .length